# what is placemark in flutter geocoding

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geocoding, google-maps-api-2

I m very beginner for flutter google maps. I just want to know what is placemark in flutter geocoding and I just need to understand the below code. Thank you so much for any help.

```
  _getAddress() async {
try {
  List<Placemark> p = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
      _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);
  Placemark place = p[0];

  setState(() {
    _currentAddress =
        "${place.name}, ${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}";
    startAddressController.text = _currentAddress;
    _startAddress = _currentAddress;
  });
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Placemark](https://pub.dev/documentation/geocoding_platform_interface/latest/geocoding_platform_interface/Placemark-class.html) is a class that contains information like place's name, locality, postalCode, country and other properties. See Properties in the documentation.

[placemarkFromCoordinates](https://pub.dev/documentation/geocoding_platform_interface/latest/geocoding_platform_interface/GeocodingPlatform/placemarkFromCoordinates.html) is a method that returns a list of Placemark instances found for the supplied coordinates.

`Placemark place = p[0]`  just gets the first Placemark from the list you got from placemarkFromCoordinates method.

The code inside the `setState` method just updates the `_currentAddress` to the place info you got from the Placemark `place` and then passes its value to the `startAddressController.text` and `_startAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

Placemark() class helps you to get certain information like city name, country name, local code based on google map api.
Before you use Placemark() in your app, you need to get decoded string info from google map api

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$request->lat.','.$request->lng.'&key='."your api key here"
```

From your server side code should return json response and then

```
_placeMark = Placemark(name: _address)
```

Now _placeMark would help you get access to city, country, local code etc.
For more go there
https://www.dbestech.com/tutorials/flutter-google-map-geocoding-and-geolocator

Comment: Please remove your unrestricted API key from your answer. This could lead to billing issues on your end. It would be better for you to delete this one and generate a new one as this could be already compromised. And also make sure that you have restricted it as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#restricting-api-keys